# Possibilities to monitor an App Registration using Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Is it possible to monitor the requests of an app registration that uses the MS Outlook Graph API to poll the inbox of a specific shared mailbox?
We get an „Application is over its MailboxConcurrency limit." error when polling the inbox, but we see not reason why this happens, we know there can only be 4 concurrent call to the api...
But to find out how often the api is called, is there a way to monitor this?

Comment: Not exactly what you want but Mailbox Auditing may help with this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/enable-mailbox-auditing?view=o365-worldwide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently that's not possible.